# Pro Webmasters Moderator Cards

Tags: discussion

We recently printed some business cards for our Stack Exchange employees and they turned out great.

It got us thinking: our sites' moderators have been working hard to keep our sites high quality for the past few years. They may not be employees, per se, but great community moderators are why our communities are safe, sane, and worth visiting in the first place..

If you're a webmasters.stackexchange moderator, would you be interested in having your own Pro Webmasters Stack Exchange contact card? Would you find it useful?

I can see them being handy to pass out during your local meetups or tech conferences.

Below is a mockup:

<sub>(click on image to see full res version)</sub>

[image: Pro Webmasters moderator cards]

Of course Twitter ID/phone# are optional. It can be Skype, AIM, URL etc.

Note: the text rendering in the mockup is slightly blurry. But when printed it will be crisp.

Answer (score 3):

OK, the cards are now available -- all current moderators were mailed a link to the form to customize the cards. Enjoy!

Comment: Is it possible to resend that email? It didn't hit my inbox for some reason. (Previous emails have been successful so this is kinda weird).

Comment: sure, I just forwarded it to you.

Comment: That failed, too. I smell an email conspiracy. If you could try just one more time using my gmail account (stymiee [at] gmail.com) I would appreciate it.

Comment: ok, I mailed it to the new address. That's two different email paths (our server code, and our hosted sent-via-gmail-webapp one) that have failed to your other email address! Definitely concerning...

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. That email came through just fine. Much appreciated. And if you want to send test emails to my address feel free. I'll let you if and when they come through.

Answer (score 2):

I would love to have some webmaster business cards!